# C# - Is there any reliable event that exists to be notified when the screen saver become active/inactive

Tags: c#, events, screensaver

I'm looking for an event that would happen when the screen saver become active or inactive. I want to be notified. I do not want to use any timer.

I do not want to poll for it. I don't want to use: SystemParametersInfo( SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING, 0, ref isRunning, 0 );

I tried that without success, I never receive the SC_SCREENSAVE...

```
    // ************************************************************************
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // ************************************************************************
    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

        IntPtr mainWindowPtr = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
        HwndSource mainWindowSrc = HwndSource.FromHwnd(mainWindowPtr);
        if (mainWindowSrc != null)
        {
            mainWindowSrc.AddHook(WndProc);
        }

        //HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
        //source.AddHook(WndProc);
    }

    // ************************************************************************
    private const Int32 WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
    private const int SC_SCREENSAVE = 0xF140;
    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        if (msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND)
        {
            Debug.Print("SysCommand : " + wParam);
            if (wParam.ToInt32() == SC_SCREENSAVE)
            {
                Debug.Print(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            }
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
```

Anybody has any other idea or does know what is wrong with my code ???

Comment: Is your code based on this answer: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4cdb1251-da4b-4693-a58f-841c64c8f8bc/screen-saver-notifications?forum=netfxbcl ? It seems to be the only available way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   if (wParam.ToInt32() == SC_SCREENSAVE)
```

That's not correct.  It is an odd quirk in the [WM_SYSCOMMAND message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), surely dating to a long gone era where they had to squeeze a GUI operating system in 640 kilobytes.  The low 4 bits in the command value are used for internal purposes.  You'll have to mask them out before you compare.  Fix:

```
   if ((wParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0) == SC_SCREENSAVE)
```

You'd probably had figured this out yourself by using the proper Debug statement formatting :)

```
   Debug.Print("SysCommand : 0x{0:X}", wParam);
```

Comment: Thanks Hans. I think my code come partly from one of your past answer. BUT ... It still does not work with the patch. Do you have any idea why ? In fact I received any "WM_SYSCOMMAND" at all. The only time I receive one (which is not SC_SCREENSAVE) it is when window is visible and I click on it. Otherwise, no WM_SYSCOMMMAND at all. It that possible that is filtered or that WM_SYSCOMMAND changed over time ???

Comment: You definitely should see more.  SC_CLOSE when you close the window with the title bar button, SC_MINIMIZE when you minimize it.  Also use the system menu.  Only requirement is that it is a toplevel window.

Comment: You are right. I see any system menu (control box) messages, minimize, ... . But No SC_SCREENSAVE. I'm trying SetwindowsHookEx and I will keep you inform about it. Thanks !!!  ... oh! and my window is the only one in my WPF app, it should be a top level one.

Comment: Hans you are right. Your solution was the appropriate one. I took me long time but I finally make "SetwindowsHookEx" to work (with your help again in another stackoverflow question) but realised that I did not received the SC_SCREENSAVE from this hook (???). The problem come from the way I activated the screensaver which it does not broadcast (I don't have my source code - very old code of mine). Thanks a lots.

Comment: I activated the screen saver by throwing a broadcast message and everything worked ok. Thanks a lots !!!

Comment: Hans, when the save screen is activated by the Windows 7 timer (regular way of activation), I do not receive any event. Is that possible that the behavior changed over time (windows 7 or a Windows update) ???

Comment: Using SystemParametersInfo with SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING work fine but it require a timer (polling) which is to my point of view: horrible poor designed code... but up to now, it is the only way I found that works all the time...  :-(

Answer (score 0):

Hans answer seems to not work for me on Windows 7 when it is activated normally by the timer (at least when your account is part of a domain and a policy make screen saver parameters as readonly).

Using SystemParametersInfo with SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING work fine but it require a timer (polling) which is to my point of view: horrible poorly designed code... but up to now, it is the only way I found that works all the time... :-(

I left my code as reference. It include many of my tests.
There is a lot more but just remove what you don't need.
You could consult the HotKey excellent class there (I couldn't found my initial source but this one is exactly the same): https://github.com/shellscape/Lumen/blob/master/Application/HotkeyHandler.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using HQ.Util.General;
using HQ.Util.Unmanaged;
using HQ.Wpf.Util;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using SpreadsheetGear;

namespace MonitorMe
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public enum HookType : int
        {
            WH_JOURNALRECORD = 0,
            WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK = 1,
            WH_KEYBOARD = 2,
            WH_GETMESSAGE = 3,
            WH_CALLWNDPROC = 4,
            WH_CBT = 5,
            WH_SYSMSGFILTER = 6,
            WH_MOUSE = 7,
            WH_HARDWARE = 8,
            WH_DEBUG = 9,
            WH_SHELL = 10,
            WH_FOREGROUNDIDLE = 11,
            WH_CALLWNDPROCRET = 12,
            WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13,
            WH_MOUSE_LL = 14
        }

        delegate IntPtr HookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private HotKeyHandeler _hotKeyHandler = null;
        private Timer _timerToMonitorScreenSaver = null;
        // ************************************************************************
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;
            Monitor.Instance.Add(SessionSwitchReason.SessionLogon);

            _timerToMonitorScreenSaver = new Timer(TimerCallbackMonitorScreenSaver, this, 3000, 3000);
        }

        private void TimerCallbackMonitorScreenSaver(object state)
        {
            int active = 1;
            SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING, 0, ref active, 0);
            if (active == 1)
            {
                Debug.Print("Timer detected Screen Saver activated on: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            }
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(HookType hookType, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

        // Signatures for unmanaged calls
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
           int uAction, int uParam, ref int lpvParam,
           int flags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
           int uAction, int uParam, ref bool lpvParam,
           int flags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd,
           int wMsg, int wParam, int lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern IntPtr OpenDesktop(
           string hDesktop, int Flags, bool Inherit,
           uint DesiredAccess);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool CloseDesktop(
           IntPtr hDesktop);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool EnumDesktopWindows(
           IntPtr hDesktop, EnumDesktopWindowsProc callback,
           IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(
           IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        // Callbacks
        private delegate bool EnumDesktopWindowsProc(
           IntPtr hDesktop, IntPtr lParam);

        // Constants
        private const int SPI_GETSCREENSAVERACTIVE = 16;
        private const int SPI_SETSCREENSAVERACTIVE = 17;
        private const int SPI_GETSCREENSAVERTIMEOUT = 14;
        private const int SPI_SETSCREENSAVERTIMEOUT = 15;
        private const int SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING = 114;
        private const int SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 2;

        private const uint DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS = 0x0080;
        private const uint DESKTOP_READOBJECTS = 0x0001;
        private const int WM_CLOSE = 16;


        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage
            (IntPtr hWnd,
            uint Msg,
            uint wParam,
            uint lParam);

        public enum SpecialHandles
        {
            HWND_DESKTOP = 0x0,
            HWND_BROADCAST = 0xFFFF
        }

        // Registers a hot key with Windows.
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);
        // Unregisters the hot key with Windows.
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);


        private IntPtr _hHook;

        // ************************************************************************
        void _hotKeyHandler_HotKeyPressed(object sender, HotKeyEventArgs e)
        {
            ActivateScreenSaver();
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        private IntPtr MessageHookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (code == WM_SYSCOMMAND)
            {
                Debug.Print("SysCommand : " + wParam);
                if ((wParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0) == SC_SCREENSAVE)
                {
                    Debug.Print("MessageHookProc" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                }
            }

            return CallNextHookEx(_hHook, code, wParam, lParam);
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        private const Int32 WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
        private const int SC_SCREENSAVE = 0xF140;
        private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            if (msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND)
            {
                Debug.Print("SysCommand : " + wParam);
                if ((wParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0) == SC_SCREENSAVE)
                {
                    // Works fine in almost all cases. I already did some code in the past which activate the screen saver
                    // but I never receive any WM_SYSCOMMAND for that code, I do not have source code for it anymore).
                    Debug.Print("WndProc" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                }
            }

            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
        {
            Monitor.Instance.Add(e.Reason);
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        private void CmdExportToExcel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ExportToExcel();
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        private void ExportToExcel()
        {
            IWorkbook wb = Factory.GetWorkbook();
            IWorksheet workSheet = wb.Worksheets[0];

            int col = 1;
            for (int dayIndex = -30; dayIndex <= 0; dayIndex++)
            {
                DateTime day = DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan(dayIndex, 0, 0, 0);
                Debug.Print(day.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

                workSheet.Cells[0, col].Value = day.DayOfWeek.ToString();
                workSheet.Cells[1, col].Value = day;

                DayMonitor dayMonitor = Monitor.Instance.DayMonitors.FirstOrDefault(dm => dm.Day == day);
                if (dayMonitor != null)
                {

                    workSheet.Cells[2, col].Value = "Last - First";
                    workSheet.Cells[2, col + 1].Value = dayMonitor.TotalHours;

                    workSheet.Cells[3, col].Value = "Has estimated time (7h00 or 18h00)";
                    workSheet.Cells[3, col + 1].Value = dayMonitor.HasSomeEstimatedHours;

                    int row = 5;
                    foreach (var state in dayMonitor.SessionLockStateChanges)
                    {
                        workSheet.Cells[row, col].Value = state.SessionSwitchReason.ToString();
                        workSheet.Cells[row, col + 1].Value = state.DateTime;
                        row++;
                    }
                }

                workSheet.Cells[1, col].ColumnWidth = 18;
                workSheet.Cells[1, col + 1].ColumnWidth = 18;

                col += 2;
            }


            if (wb != null)
            {
                if (FileAssociation.IsFileAssociationExistsForExtensionWithDot(".xlsx"))
                {
                    string path = TempFolderAutoClean.GetTempFileName("xlsx", "Export ");
                    wb.SaveAs(path, FileFormat.OpenXMLWorkbook);

                    Process p = new Process();
                    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                    p.StartInfo.FileName = path;
                    p.Start();
                }
                else
                {
                    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                    saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
                    saveFileDialog.Filter = "Excel file (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
                    saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";

                    if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog(Application.Current.MainWindow) == true)
                    {
                        string path = saveFileDialog.FileName;
                        wb.SaveAs(path, FileFormat.OpenXMLWorkbook);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        private void PrintOnExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ExportToExcel();
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        private void ExitOnExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        private void PrintOnCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
            e.ContinueRouting = false;
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        private void ExitOnCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
            e.ContinueRouting = false;
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        private void CmdLaunchScreenSaver_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ActivateScreenSaver();
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        private void ActivateScreenSaver()
        {
            // Next won't work in a secured Screen Saver by Account Policy (ex: by a domain policy)
            //int nullVar = 0;
            //SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETSCREENSAVERACTIVE, 1, ref nullVar, SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);

            // This works fine all the time... and also send appropriate message to every top level window
            SendMessage(new IntPtr((int)SpecialHandles.HWND_BROADCAST), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_SCREENSAVE, 0);
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        private void MainWindow_OnInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int error;
            IntPtr hMod = LoadLibrary("user32.dll"); // Hans Passant info in stackOverflow

            _hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(HookType.WH_GETMESSAGE, MessageHookProc, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); // Error 87

            _hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(HookType.WH_GETMESSAGE, MessageHookProc, hMod, (uint)Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); // Error 87

            _hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(HookType.WH_GETMESSAGE, MessageHookProc, hMod, 0);
            error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); // Work fine, got a hook, but never receive the WM_SYSCOMMAND:SC_SCREENSAVE
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        // ************************************************************************
        protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

            // Method 1

            //IntPtr mainWindowPtr = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
            //HwndSource mainWindowSrc = HwndSource.FromHwnd(mainWindowPtr);
            //if (mainWindowSrc != null)
            //{
            //  mainWindowSrc.AddHook(WndProc);
            //}

            // Method 2
            HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
            source.AddHook(WndProc);

            _hotKeyHandler = new HotKeyHandeler(this);
            _hotKeyHandler.HotKeyPressed += _hotKeyHandler_HotKeyPressed;
            //  _hotKeyHandler.RegisterHotKey(0, Key.NumPad0);

            this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        // ************************************************************************




    }
}
```